# How to configure and capture buffer overflow in intel processor trace

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, trace, processor

I try simple-pt in https://github.com/andikleen/simple-pt

It seens that the buffer is used as ring.

If internal buffer overflow occurs, can tracing pause itself and make the kernel module handle it?

Comment: And why not to use latest kernel with `perf` tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double buffer approach with two ToPA tables with STOP bit set to 1 on each table. The Intel PT hardware will always fill one buffer while your program (userspace) reads from the other. The user will be responsible for swapping buffer once it reads all the data from its buffer. If the hardware buffer fills up the STOP bit will stop tracing and set the STOPPED bit on the IA32_RTIT_STATUS MSR. You can then check this bit in order to determine if a buffer overflow occured.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have alreadly known how to trigger PMI